# How do I install a Perl module with specific permissions

Tags: perl, module, installation

I'm trying to get multiple people to update an installed Perl by using group permissions in UNIX and the usual Makefile created out of `ExUtils::MakeMaker`

On a plain install, Makemaker ignores the umask and the PERM_RW variable in the Makefile and creates the installed file with the permissions

```
24 -r--r--r--    1 UID    GROUP        23536 May 01 15:23 Ftp.pm
```

This is plainly wrong for my purpose. How do I get makemaker to install files with the following permissions:

```
24 -rw-rw-r--    1 UID    GROUP        23536 May 01 15:23 Ftp.pm
```

so that they're usable by members of  GROUP?

Comment: wrap `cpan` in a shell script that runs `chmod g+w` after the install.

Comment: The `umask` limits permissions, so whether MM ignores the umask or not is irrelevant since you're saying you want more permission, not less.

Comment: This smells like a bug in EUMM. And I checked version 5.48 from 2002, it seems that this bug is forever there. Only man pages were affected by PERM_RW, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get makemaker to install files [...] so that they're usable by members of GROUP?

The permissions you said the module has are sufficient for members of group GROUP to use it. (As you can see, the group permissions are the same as the user permissions.) Only read permission is needed on modules. You've already accomplished your stated goal.

Comment: As I read the question, he wants any member of the group to be able to **install** an updated version of the module.

Comment: I get them to ignore the warning. It's a UNIX issue; one user cannot change permissions on a file which owned by another user. I apologise for not mentioning the warning earlier.

Comment: What warning? No warning was mentioned.

Comment: Sorry - not used to this interface. Thank you for your answer.